# Как верстают топ компании под мобильные устройства?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, вёрстка, мобильная-разработка

Верстаю сайт для пиццерии и смотрю на примеры топовых компаний вроде додо. Пока крутил и вертел в браузере верстку, заметил, что при запросе с "мобильных устройств" выдаёт абсолютно другой сайт. Пытаюсь найти инфу в интернете и ничего не получается. Пишу на реакте, хочется сделать нормально, а не резиновую вёрстку. Подскажите, добрые люди, что за птица такая? как сделать также?

Comment: на бекенде смотрят с какого браузера идет запрос и если это считается мобильным браузером, то просто отдается мобильная версия сайта. Можно такое на vk.com/m.vk.com посмотреть еще

Comment: @ThisMan Я сделал фронт на реакте и бэк на питоне, где именно я должен отслеживать запрос? По логике на реакте? тк бэк только json-ом отвечает на запросы. Если я прав, то где можно инфу по этому поводу почитать или посмотреть?

Comment: там где отдаете статику на фронт (html, js, css)

Comment: вообще, обычно делают специальный домен, куда просто редиректят, а на том домене уже раздаются нужные файлы. Не знаю можно ли на условном nginx сделать такие редиректы, но если нельзя, тогда просто в точке входа самой первой